# Match string between quotes only for the strings that have a certain sub-string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with data from browser history and want to extract with notepad++ all the URL strings that have a certain format. Specifically, I want to extract all the text between quotes when the substring

`www.linkedin.com/jobs/view`

is present. So for instance if I have the line

```
"url": "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/240035516?trkInfo\u003dsearchKeywordString%3AVolvo%2BGroup%2CsearchLocation"
```

I want to match

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/240035516?trkInfo\u003dsearchKeywordString%3AVolvo%2BGroup%2CsearchLocation
```

I want to do this in order to extract all of those URL's to a separate file.

I got from another post the regex

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

to match everything that is enclosed in double quotes. But I know nothing about regex and don't really know how to adapt the above expression to my problem. How can I change it?

Comment: Why not use a simpler `"[^"]*www\.linkedin\.com/jobs/view[^"]*"`? Are there any escaped quotes in the input?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that fits my problem. As I wrote, I know nothing about regex, and needed a fast solution so was kind of shooting in the dark for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no need to support escaped quotes, you may rely on a much simpler regex that is based on negated character classes:

```
"[^"]*www\.linkedin\.com/jobs/view[^"]*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hOmvaO/1)

The dots must be escaped to match a literal dot, and `[^"]*` (a *negated* character class) matches any 0+ chars other than a `"`.

Answer (score 0):

To match a line like: `"url": "Path to website"` in Notepad++ you can use:

```
"url":\s*"\K[^"]*(?=")
```